# Push notification whenever there is a change in database Flutter

Tags: laravel, flutter, dart

I'm getting some data (Product list) from my `Database` using `API` `(Laravel)` and show them inside my app.

I have a form in my app where I can `add a new product` information and add it to the database .

I want whenever there is a new product added, the app sends a `push notification` to all the users.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to configure your server part(laravel) with a notification service like firebase.

and after, connect and receive a notification whenever the data changes.

[you can click here for reference](https://medium.com/@samiwimalarathne/send-push-notifications-using-onesignal-with-flutter-firebase-php-laravel-81a37dd7a0fc)